# sequential promise chain with array of data, how to resolve the promise chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am using kriskowal q implementation.

I have an array of data objects, each with an id.

I need to chain these sequentially into promises because I am abiding to rate limiting rules by setting it to 1 request per second.

However, I am having trouble resolving the promises and my function stalls. I.e. I see the ouput of addVideo, getInfo, retryIfNeeded and a delay of 1 second for the very first video, but I don't see any of that for any subsequent videos.

What I want to do is after the delay, to resolve that chain so that the next list of promises continues on the second Video ID.

How do I do this? What am I doing wrong? I've searched a lot on google but haven't found a solution so any suggestions is welcome

Edit added jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gpa7ym18/4

```
var promiseChain = data.items.reduce(function(promise, video) {
  video.type = type;
  return promise
         .then(addVideo)
         .then(getInfo)
         .then(retryIfNeeded)
         .then( function() {
            return q.delay(1000)
                   .done(function() {
                        NEED TO RESOLVE HERE but there is NO Defered object
                        to set defer.resolve. How do I resolve this promise chain?
                   });
         });
   }, q.resolve(data.items[0]));
```

Comment: Just `return`, as always? But use `then`, never `done`.

Comment: but I tried removing the last .then and .done but it didn't resolve

Comment: is it because I use q.resolve(data.items[0])

Comment: Starting with `data.items[0]` instead of undefined is weird, but should not cause problems. What do you mean, "it didn't resolve"? Have you put a log statement in `addVideo`? Does that function expect any parameters? Did you try adding handlers (especially error handlers) to `promiseChain`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes there are log statements in each function. each function requires a parameter which comes from `data.items`. Basically `data.items` is an array of `videoIds` and this get's passed down the chain from `addVideo` to `getInfo` to `retryIfNeeded`. I see the logs for `addVideo`, `getInfo`, and `retryIfNeeded`, but then it stalls and doesn't go to `videoId2`. Hence I don't think it is resolving after the last promise

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gpa7ym18/4/ which shows that the promises don't pass in the `data.items id`. How do I pass that data?

Comment: To the contrary - it resolves fine, but with `undefined` - that's the result you get from `Q.delay`. You should explicitly use the `video` variable that you get passed from `reduce`, e.g. like `promise.then(function(prevResult){ return addVideo(video); })…`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resolve anything.

You should simply return the delayed promise, and that will become the value of the entire chain.
This is exactly how promise chaining works.

Comment: can you take a look at my comments I've added and see if you can help me? I basically want to act on each object in my array with a sequence promises and chain that

Comment: @Chowza: You need to bind `video` to your function as a parameter: `.then(addVideo.bind(null, video))`.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: Accepting answer as  this, along with the comments from bergi helped me answer this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/gpa7ym18/8/ illustrated my solution